# QGIS does not display all Features of Layer and behaves weird instead

Tags: qgis, postgis

I have a weird problem with QGIS trying to load a Layer from a Postgis Database

When I open the Layer from Postsgis I have two choices:

**Method one**:

Either, I use the Panel "Browser", where I can select PostGIS->myDatabase->public->myTable

then, I get a subset of the features in the table to be displayed in the main section (namely, only those features that have been edited via geoserver, but there is absolutely no trace of that in the datbase table).
The subset consists of 338 features, while the whole table contains 5380 features.

When I rightclick the Layer's Name in the "Layer" Panel and select "open attribute table", I still get a List with all Features in the table, even those that are not displayed. When I select one of the non-displayed features and click the Loupe Icon ("zoom to the chosen cell"), It zooms to the place where the feature would be expected but is not displayed.

When I rightclick the Layer's Name  and select "show numbers of object" it shows correctly 5402

But when I rightclick the Layer in the "Browser" Panel and select "properties", it says "Number of Objects within the layer":338

**Method two**

The second option I have is, open the layer with the Elephant-Icon on the left taskbar.

With this process, I get a layer where all 5402 features are correctly displayed - BUT:

When I try to select features in order to copy or move them, it works only with these 338 features from the other selection. The remaining 5064 features are simply not selectable. When I click on them after I selected the "select objects" button, nothing happens at all.

**---**

Even when I edit the values of on feature of the 5064 to resemble exactly the values of one of the 338 (except for Id), it is still not displayed in method one and not selectable in method two.

Everything worked fine before. Without any obvious reason, the program decided to behave like this.

Who can help?

---

Screenshot of info tab of the respective table
[image]

Comment: How did you create the other features in PostGIS (as opposed to the ones that were edited)? My initial thought is the ones that are not coming in correctly may not have an SRID set or are similarly malformed.

Comment: the features were all originally imported to the database from a shapefile via qgis. how can I check the srid?

Comment: Use the database manager in QGIS (Database menu); when you browse to the PostGIS table in the tree, the 'info' tab has a "Spatial ref" entry which shows the SRID.

Comment: If you export the data to a new shapefile, how many features are taken?

Comment: @Simbamangu: In the info tab, I dont see any information about "spatial ref", but in the table tree on the left hand, I see a table called "spatial_ref_sys".  This contains a column called "srid" and about 4000 entries. How do I figure out now which of the entries are corrupt and belong to the broken features in my table? Asante sana!

Comment: When you __select__ your table in the tree, on the right there should be information about that table (options of three tabs: 'info', 'table', 'preview' - select 'info'), one line of which is 'spatial ref'.

Comment: there is actually no spatial_ref line, look at screenshot

Comment: Next to your table, there should be a table `geometry_columns`, with one line for every table stating the srid. But as the warning in your screenshot shows, that information is missing in that table. And the `Geometry:` type should be POINT, LINESTRING or POLYGON, but not GEOMETRY.

Comment: The screenshot confirms that there is no SRID set ("No entry in geometry_columns"). Please also try to add the layer again but look at the log (View|Panels|Log messages) for PostGIS and see if it is throwing errors.

Comment: it says: Feature type or srid for GEOMETRY of "public"."Graeber" could not be determined or was not requested.

Comment: Where in the Database is this srid info supposed to be stored?

Comment: I think the SRID issue is missleading. The program consists of several other layers as well that lack the "entry in geometry_columns" as well,  but  work fine concerning the ability of being marked for selection (Method one) and being loaded and displayed via the browser panel (Method two)

Comment: Agreed, it doesn't need to be explicitly set (it's in a table called geometry_columns, which stores the table name together with the geometry column and its SRID); I was also hoping there would be more explanatory errors (like bad geometry) appearing in the log. I'd suggest exporting the layer directly from PostGIS as a shapefile and see what you get ...